# Do not count a specific TR in a table, and apply Even/Odd CSS style to all others

Tags: jquery, css

I want to style a table, giving a blue background color to every second row.

However, I want to ignore a specific row - the second one - from this styling rule.

This means that even though there are 4 rows, I want to treat them as 3 rows, so that row 1 is odd, row 2 doesn't exist, row 3 is even, and row 4 is odd.

I tried using `not` or defining `reg` class for all regular rows, but it didn't help.

My expected result would be to have row 3 in blue color. 
Result in fact: row 4 is in blue color.

(The logic for my objective: in my real project, row 2 is not really a "row", I use it to add info related to row 1)

```css
tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

table#aa tr:not(.jack):nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: blue;
}

table#bb tr.reg:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="aa">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="jack">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    
<div>another try</div>

<table id="bb">
  <tr class="reg">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="reg">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="reg">
    <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

- I don't necessarily have only 4 rows. I might have 20 in another
  example.
- The second row is second in this particular example. but it can
  the third or the fourth in another example. The main issue is how to 
  skip it, without using any "fixed" definitions.

Comment: You'll need JS/JQ to index the selected rows, exclude the ones you don't want, and then style accordingly. CSS can't do this with an `nth` selector`.

Comment: I managed to do it with JQ, but it's not elegant. it firstly loads single color, and only when pages finish loading, it changes the color for the relevant cells.

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer, please check this codepen for a working example:

https://codepen.io/niorad/pen/dJrqGp

It's possible with some sibling-trickery.

```
table .out:not(:nth-child(odd)) ~ tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: blue;
}

table .out:not(:nth-child(odd)) ~ tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: green;
}

table .out:not(:nth-child(even)) ~ tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: blue;
}

table .out:not(:nth-child(even)) ~ tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Two problems: (a) I don't necessarily have only 4 rows. I might have 20. (b) The second row is second in this example. but it can the third or the fourth in another example. The main issue is how to skip it, without using "fixed" definitions.

Comment: nice try but If I delete the `.jack` TR, with this code, all 3/3 TRs will have the same background color. so it is not a solution...

Comment: no they won't. if you check out the codepen-example, and remove the tr with the .out class, you'll get your normal striped table.

Comment: Ok, you're correct, but after testing, I see it will work only for the first `.out`. If I have 2 TRs with an `.out` class, the second of them will get normal colors rather than special, so this rule is currently not universal enough.. any way to improve it?

Comment: Hmm, you didn't state that there can be multiple special rows. I think it's possible but you would end up with a bunch of unreadable css-selectors. It would be easier if you rendered your table with "odd" and "even" classes to start with, and style those directly.

Comment: interesting idea. I will try it. perhaps there's some little tweak though for your code to allow multiple ones?

Comment: Do you need to use <tr> for the extra-rows? Would a div or something else be possible? Then it might work.

Comment: This can only work if you use not classes, but different elements to differentiate the special row. It seems to work with a mix of tbody and theads, but this is no proper html!
https://codepen.io/niorad/pen/NXmaXK
As far as I can tell, you can only use <tr> as table rows, thus the hack with tbody and thead.

Comment: (Reason: for this to work, you need nth-of-type. nth-of-type unfortunately doesn't work with classes, only with elements like <tr>, <td> and the like)

Comment: one of the problems with using a DIV rather than TR is that I want to display some CSS-animated text inside this TR, and if it's a DIV the animation looks more glitchy for some reason

Comment: Where's the problem with adding "odd" and "even" classes when you render the table? It seems the easiest way AFAICT.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I simply didn't thought out about this option, I will use that one, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`:odd` and `:even` selectors will take all siblings in account. 
You'll have to combine some CSS rules to get what you want.

```
td{width:100px;height:100px;background-color: green}

table#aa tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: blue;
}
table#aa tr.jack td {
    background-color: red;
}
table#aa tr:first-child td {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Since you want the third one to be blue, you better select the odd rows, this will automatically make the third row blue. The first one you can force to be green, and the second one you can force a red background-color or add some different styles if you like.

[I've this jsFiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/mwd4axap/1/)

Comment: Two problems: (a) I don't necessarily have only 4 rows. I might have 20.  (b) The second row is second in this example. but it can the third or the fourth in another example. The main issue is how to skip it, without using "fixed" definitions.

Comment: Okay, I think I've had a similar need in some project once. Wouldn't it be easier to have nested tables in each parent table row... That way, you can have 2 rows in each nested table, one for data display, the other as 'toolbar'.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd like to change my whole table structure just because of this background issue. sounds likes an overkill and too much mess that can lead to other styling problems... Currently I have one table, it's also better practice for SEO I think.

Comment: When exactly will this 'second' row be shown? Is it like a 'show more' on each row? Could you provide a more real-life case instead of colored cells? Might be easier to get what you're looking for.

Comment: I will have a PHP condition. wheneven condition takes place for any given "normal" TR, the "special" TR should be created beneath the normal TR.

Comment: Okay. And will the special tr hold buttons or something else? Do the main table heading makes any sense for the special tr?

Comment: Yes it will have some elements inside of it. If you mean THEAD part, no, I already use it for real table headers. Also I might have to use the special TR more than once per table.

Comment: If the special row does not relate to thead contents, for SEO purpose.. it would be better not to use a row. You can add other types of element and position it with css where you would like it to render. Pushing down the next sibling tr with margin/padding would make it look like the extra element is inside the tbody

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

**JQuery solution**

This selects all the rows that do *not* have the chosen class, filters them and colors each alternate row red.

```js
$("table tr:not('.jack')").filter(":odd").children().css("background-color", "red");
```

```css
tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.jack td {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="aa">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="jack">
    <td>Not here</td>
    <td>Not here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this before page finish loading? otherwise the color will change with some delay

Comment: That's a different question. Probably but my knowledge does not extend that far.

Comment: If it has to be done before page has finished loading, you might be better of printing classes on each tr in PHP on the server side. You mentioned if conditions before, use them to see what class a tr should have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add a dummy `<tr></tr>` above the ones you don't want to count?

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>odd row</td></tr>
  <tr id="dummy"></tr>
  <tr><td>skip count</td></tr>
  <tr><td>even row</td></tr>
</table>
```